Huge Bounds on Forecast Interval for ARIMA model
I'm working on a financial forecast and trying out a simple SARIMA model to try and forecast the year of 2025. I think the predicted values and fit of the model are fine, and I've tested out many different versions of the SARIMA and the version I've written has the best metrics for fit. For context, the values I'm ultimately trying to predict are mostly on the order of millions (10^6) and have some decent variation, from 100k-6m.
That said, I'm not super familiar with forecast predictive intervals, and I'm receiving some huge bounds for my 95% forecast interval.
To achieve stationarity I am doing first differences of the natural log of the response. I fear that the back transform I'm doing is what may be causing my issues. I transform my data like so:
net_new <- read.csv('net_new_arr_monthly.csv')
net_new$log_net <- log(net_new$net_new_arr)

first.diff <- diff(x = net_new$log_net, lag = 1, 
                   differences = 1)

And model it with:
mod.fit <- arima(x = first.diff, order= c(1,0,0), seasonal= list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12))


I was thinking that I would use the SE of the residuals from the model to create the intervals. Here is how I did the intervals:
fore.mod <- as.data.frame(predict(object = mod.fit, n.ahead = 15, se.fit = TRUE))

fore.mod$lwr <- fore.mod$pred - qnorm(p = 0.975, mean = 0, sd = sd(mod.fit$residuals))*fore.mod$se
fore.mod$upr <- fore.mod$pred + qnorm(p = 0.975, mean = 0, sd = sd(mod.fit$residuals))*fore.mod$se

pred.trans = data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(fore.mod)){
    pred.trans[i,"pred"] <- exp(net_new$log_net[nrow(net_new)]+sum(fore.mod$pred[1:i]))
    pred.trans[i,"lwr"] <- exp(net_new$log_net[nrow(net_new)]+sum(fore.mod$lwr[1:i]))
    pred.trans[i,"upr"] <- exp(net_new$log_net[nrow(net_new)]+sum(fore.mod$upr[1:i]))
}

I suppose I'm wondering if I'm correct in my thinking so far? Do I have to just deal with large bounds simply because of the nature of the data? Is the back transform done correctly? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

What does your title mean? What do you mean by bounds on interval? Does it mean you are concerned that your forecast intervals are very wide, or is it something more complicated than that? If the former, consider reformulating the title accordingly.

You cannot simply add up the upper and lower bounds of intervals. Let R do the calculation for you:
mod.fit <- arima(log(net_new$net_new_arr), 
  order= c(1,1,0), seasonal= list(order = c(0,1,1), period = 12))
fore.mod <- predict(object = mod.fit, n.ahead = 15, se.fit = TRUE) |>
  as.data.frame()
fore.mod$lwr <- exp(fore.mod$pred - qnorm(p = 0.975)*fore.mod$se)
fore.mod$upr <- exp(fore.mod$pred + qnorm(p = 0.975)*fore.mod$se)
fore.mod$pred <- exp(fore.mod$pred)

While this will give you correct prediction intervals, note that the point forecast (pred) will be biased. In fact, you can interpret the back-transformed pred value as the median of the forecast distribution (rather than the mean).
To do the bias correction, and simplify your code even further, you can use the forecast package:
library(forecast)
mod.fit2 <- Arima(net_new$net_new_arr, 
  order= c(1,1,0), seasonal= list(order = c(0,1,1), period = 12), lambda = 0)
fore.mod2 <- forecast(mod.fit2, h = 15, biasadj = TRUE) |>
    as.data.frame()

The lambda argument here is for a Box-Cox transformation, and lambda=0 is equivalent to a logarithm. The forecast() function will automatically backtransform the forecasts and apply the bias-correction.
See my book (Forecasting: Principles & Practice) for more information.
